# In a function, how to get all *assigned* (not bound) parameters?

Tags: powershell

I have a function with some parameters. It then creates an object and assigns those parameter values as properties of the object. How would I programmatically get any parameter values that have been assigned (whether by a default value, or bound at runtime)? Here's my code:

```
function New-Label {
    param (
        [string] $text,
        [string] $name,
        [boolean] $autoSize = $true,
        [System.Drawing.Color] $foreColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Black
    )
    $label = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.AutoSize = $autoSize
    $label.ForeColor = $foreColor
    foreach ($pair in $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator()){
        $label.$pair.Key = $pair.Value
    }
    return $label
}
```

For user-bound parameters at runtime, the `$PSBoundParameters` works fine but I don't like that I have to manually assign the `AutoSize` and `ForeColor` properties just because they aren't "bound" at runtime.

Not to mention, it gets tedious if there are a large number of properties and it'd be more efficient to simply loop through them.

Is there some way to get any parameters with *assigned* values (including default values--not just *bound* parameters)--which would be `$autoSize` and `$foreColor`, plus `$text` and/or `$name`, whichever have been assigned by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use `$PSBoundParameters` in this case, to check which parameters are not being bound and to add them dynamically to `$PSBoundParameters` you can use the following:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

function New-Label {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string] $text,
        [string] $name,
        [boolean] $autoSize = $true,
        [System.Drawing.Color] $foreColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Black
    )

    # get all parameters of this command excluding common ones
    [System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata]::new($MyInvocation.MyCommand).Parameters.GetEnumerator() |
        # filter them where they're not bound
        Where-Object { -not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($_.Key) } |
        # add them to `$PSBoundParameters`
        ForEach-Object { $PSBoundParameters[$_.Key] = $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue($_.Key) }

    # cast label from the hash
    [System.Windows.Forms.Label] $PSBoundParameters
}

# check if it works
New-Label -text foo -name bar |
    Select-Object text, name, autosize, forecolor
```

Also, have a look at **[Creating Objects from hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2#creating-objects-from-hashtables)**.